# Saving images from Socket in Java, Corrupting Image

Tags: java, image, sockets, bufferedreader, mjpeg

I'm having issues with trying to receive an image (JPEG) from an MJPEG stream.
I'm connecting to the Pi and opening a socket and buffered Reader to read the lines in, taking into account the Header Responses and BoudaryStrings.
The issue I'm having is when i read all the Lines of the image and save it to a .jpg file when i view it its corrupt colored mess.
Anyone have any way to help me in this situation ? or any recommendations?

My end goal is to have the Stream being shown on a Swing GUI by repainting the image.
[image: Image Outputs]

```
 public class clientReceive {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    String ContentType;
    int ContentLength;
    int count = 0, bString = 0;
    int i = 0;

    File outputFile = new File("./images/" + i + ".jpg");
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
    String formatName = "jpeg";

    byte[] b = new byte[30000];
    Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.18", 8081);
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();

    // Read response from web server, which will trigger the multipart HTTP request
    // to be sent.
    BufferedReader httpResponseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String lineRead;

    while ((lineRead = httpResponseReader.readLine()) != null) {

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("./images/" + i + ".jpg", true));

        /*How every Image Frame is Separated
         * --BoundaryString 
         * Content-type: image/jpeg 
         * Content-Length: 26051
         */
        if (lineRead.equalsIgnoreCase("--BoundaryString")) {
            lineRead = httpResponseReader.readLine();
            if (lineRead.equalsIgnoreCase("Content-type: image/jpeg")) {
                lineRead = httpResponseReader.readLine();
                if (lineRead.contains("Content-Length:")) {
                    lineRead = httpResponseReader.readLine();

                    // System.out.println(lineRead);
                    while (!lineRead.equalsIgnoreCase("--BoundaryString")) {
                        lineRead = httpResponseReader.readLine();
                        System.out.println(lineRead);
                        out.println(lineRead);
                        // bufferedImage=ImageIO.read(is);
                    }
                    // System.out.println(lineRead);
                    // out.println(lineRead);

                    // ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,formatName,outputFile);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears you are ignoring the first line of the input data, consider moving the `lineRead` assignment to the end of the innermost `while` block

Comment: Using readline on data which is not text is not really working reliable. But more then that: You should use  use https://hc.apache.org/ instead of trying to write your own http parser.

Comment: I do this on purpose to avoid corrupting the image all together with a blank line at the start of the file. Moving the lineRead to where you say takes the blank line after the separation headers and inserts it into the .jpg file thus preventing the image from being able to be opened because the first line will have no file format data.

Comment: Wouldn't it not make any difference what data its reading as long as its saved into the appropriate file extension? using the Apache library seems a bit overkill for my use does it not  ?

Comment: Readers are for reading characters, not arbitrary bytes. By using a Reader you are almost guaranteed to corrupt the data. An existing, well-regarded library will almost certainly be more likely to get it right than you are.

Comment: Any suggestion on which library or how? I've been reading and researching this question for I don't know how long and still have gotten nowhere.

Comment: Looks like you want something that can easily handle multipart content. It looks like the Apache HTTP Client and Google HTTP client libraries can both do it.